# How do I specify POST parameters in wfetch

Tags: testing, post

I am testing an API, how do I specify the parameters to be passed for a POST request in [Microsoft's `wfetch.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778443)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set "Advanced Request" dropdown to "Add Headers & Body"

then in the textbox put:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
Field1=value&Field2=value2\r\n
```

If you have a large amount of form data to post you can use the "from file" option

Comment: The part here that I was missing is that there needs to be a \r\n between the headers and body sections for wfetch to use the input correctly.

Comment: \r\n after fields doesnt work for me I just removed if and it worked